# C++ OpenMP directives for a parallel for loop?

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying OpenMP on a particular code snippet. Not sure if the snippet needs a revamp, perhaps it is set up too rigidly for sequential implementation. Anyway here is the (pseudo-)code that I'm trying to parallelize:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(id, local_info, current_local_cell_id, local_subdomain_size) shared(cells, current_global_cell_id, global_id)
for(id = 0; id < grid_size; ++id) {
   local_info = cells.get_local_subdomain_info(id);
   local_subdomain_size = local_info.size();
   ...do other stuff...
   do {
      current_local_cell_id = cells.get_subdomain_cell_id(id);
      global_id.set(id, current_global_cell_id + current_local_cell_id);
   } while(id < local_subdomain_size && ++id);
   current_global_cell_id += local_subdomain_size;
}
```

This makes complete sense (after staring at it for some time) in a sequential sense, which also might mean that it needs to be re-written for OpenMP. My concern is that current_local_cell_id and local_subdomain_size are private, but current_global_cell_id and global_id are shared.

Hence the statement *current_global_cell_id += local_subdomain_size* after the inner loop:

```
do {
  ...
} while(...)
current_global_cell_id += local_subdomain_size;
```

might lead to errors in the OpenMP setting, I suspect. I would greatly appreciate if any of the OpenMP experts out there can provide some pointers on any of the special OMP directives I can use to make minimum changes to the code but still avail of OpenMP for such a type of for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your code. However, I think you really want some kind of parallel accumulation.

You could use a pattern like

```
 size_t total = 0;
 #pragma omp parallel for shared(total) reduction (+:total)
 for (int i=0; i<MAXITEMS; i++)
 {
      total += getvalue(i); // TODO replace with your logic
 }

 // total has been 'magically' combined by OMP
```

On a related note, when you use gcc you can just use the `__gnu_parallel::accumulate` drop-in replacement for `std::accumulate`, which does `exactly` the same. See [Chapter 18. Parallel Mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt03ch18s03.html)

```
 size_t total = __gnu_parallel::accumulate(c.begin(), c.end(), 0, &myvalue_accum);
```

You can even compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL` which will make all use of `std` algorithms automatically parallellized if possible. *Don't use that unless you know what you're doing! Frequently, performance just suffers and the chance of introducing bugs due to unexpected parallelism is real*

Comment: added hints on GNU parallel mode

Answer (score 1):

changing id inside the loop is not correct. There is no way to dispatch the loop to different thread, as loop step does not produce a predictable id value.

Why are you using the id inside that do while loop?

Comment: Sigh! You might be right. I was hoping to avoid changing that. But I think if I made current_global_cell_id also private, it might still work, no?

Comment: It's not really global then ;-) What that variable is used for? An it won't work until id is not changed in the loop